# How to use Invoke Required and invoke in console application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I am trying to convert an `Winform` application into an console application. `Winform` application had an `delegate handler`. How can I write the same functionality in `console` application? What is the alternative of `this.InvokeRequired` and `this.Invoke`

```
public delegate void DelegateMessage( string Reply );

_pipeServer.PipeMessage += new DelegateMessage( PipesMessageHandler );

private void PipesMessageHandler( string message ) {
    try {
        if ( this.InvokeRequired ) {
            this.Invoke(new NewMessageDelegate(PipesMessageHandler), message);
        }
        else {
            txtMessage.Text = message;
        }
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        Debug.WriteLine( ex.Message );
    }

}
```

Comment: Apples and oranges.  The difference between a GUI app and a non-GUI app including `console apps` is that the latter do **not** have a `message pump`.  If you managed to somehow display a GUI correctly in your 'console app' it would then by definition be a GUI app!

Comment: `TextBox` control should not in `Console` Application !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.

The `Invoke`-across-threads machinery is built on top of the Windows message loop.

What you can do if you really need a cross-thread call is to create a hidden window and start a message loop (using UI and having a console are not mutually exclusive), do your work, show results on console, and use Invoke when needed to perform actions back on the main thread.

But the main reason for needing to perform actions on the main thread is gone if you don't have any UI, also.  You've jumped to "what is the equivalent of `InvokeRequired`?" without first finding an equivalent for the TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Textbox was just to show the messages, it will now send the messages to the named pipes instead of showing it. But the event functionality which was listening the messages has invoke and invoke required. That is why i am not sure how to do it

Comment: @Shiv: `Invoke` is NEVER required for writing to a named pipe.

Comment: I know, there is an delegate in the sample code which was using it. So thats why i tried.

Comment: @Shiv: That pattern just causes the current function to run on a different thread.  There's no need to replace it, when the function doesn't use any code that has thread affinity.  Just wipe it all away, and leave only the "running on this thread is fine" path, because running on this thread IS fine.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you are saying. Thanks Ben. +1 for making me understand the logic .